# Subscribe to redis channel (pubsub) using lettuce reactive commands

Tags: java, redis, project-reactor, lettuce

I am using the [io.lettuce.core](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core) library and I am having trouble subscribing to a channel using the `RedisPubSubReactiveCommands` interface.

I have a `StatefulRedisPubSubConnection` and an active redis cluster which I am attempting to subscribe to.

`connection.sync().subscribe("channel")` works fine, as does `connection.async().subscribe("channel")`. However, when I use the reactive 'hot observable' interface provided by lettuce like so:

```
connection.reactive().subscribe(channels).subscribe();
connection.reactive().observeChannels().doOnNext(this::notifyObservers).subscribe();
```

It will not register as a subscription action on redis. I feel like I'm following the example given in the [lettuce documentation](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#pubsub.reactive-api) closely.

I'm programming for an interface that accepts a hot `Flux` Observable and I'm getting close to wrapping the sync or async connection interfaces with my own reactive wrapper and throwing them in the pipe. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this same problem, it turns out I was passing in a `Set<String>` Object into a function that accepts a varargs `Object...` and didn't realize it was treating the entire collection as a single element instead of parsing it as a varargs array.

I'll leave this up for others to learn from my dumb mistake.

Comment: Example please ?!

This is not working for me:  
<code>
String channel = "\__\key*\__\:*";
connection.reactive().subscribe(channel).subscribe();
</code>
Ignore backslash in String (cannot get comment formatted properly).

Comment: The example is here: https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/#pubsub.reactive-api


I can't help you if I do not know what is not working.